# Find the value of cdf in a point given distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Random variable has a distribution with density function $g(x,y)=1_{\{0 \le y\le 1-|x|\}}$

Find value of cdf of $(X,Y)$ in a point $(1, 0.5)$.
This should be the double integral obviously, my guess is $$\int_0^1 \int_x^{0.5} g(x,y) dydx$$
However i am not certain about that and i do not think it's correct thus what should be the solution?

Comment: Take the picture you drew for your previous question. We want the probability that $X\le 1$ and $Y\le 0.5$. Identify the point $(1,0.5)$ in the picture. You can see that we simply want $\Pr(Y\le 0.5)$. This can be computed from the density function of $Y$ that you found earlier. Or else from the geometry the probability that $Y\gt 0.5$ is the area of the top half of the triangle, which is $1/4$, so our required probability is $3/4$.

Comment: You are welcome.